# Как убрать курсив в python telebot

Tags: python, telebot

bot.edit_message_text(f' *Добро* пожаловать в @anan_as\n Наш *бот*: @anan_as', parse_mode='Markdown')

"*" - делает текст жирным

а слова между _ в словах @anan_as получаются курсивом, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Заэкранируйте эти символы слешом `\`:

```
bot.edit_message_text(f' Добро пожаловать в @anan\\_as\n Наш бот: @anan\\_as', parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Об этом написано в [документации по API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) бота.

Comment: благодарю, долго не мог найти информацию

Comment: Можно было бы использовать html и все. Там не будет такого